Name of a YA book about a girl who undergoes secret experimental surgery that makes her super smart
I last read this book some 10+ years ago and I could swear the title is 'M' something.
The main character gets in an accident and undergoes secret experimental surgery that both saves her life and makes her super smart. I also remember one specific scene where she performs neurosurgery on herself in the shower, using normal household equipment. Another thing that occurs frequently is, after the surgery, she begins hallucinating a dead raccoon that speaks to her.

Is this Mad Skills (2010) by Walter Greatshell...?

Unconscious for fourteen months after a debilitating accident, Maddy Grant awakens at the Braintree Institute, where scientists have successfully implanted her with a radical technology designed to correct her brain injury. But Maddy is more than cured. Her intellect has been enhanced to process information faster than a computer—an ability that’s sending her emotions into overdrive.
To monitor her condition, the institute sends Maddy to the nearby village of Harmony, where she will be free to interact with the community. But Braintree’s scientists are not only monitoring her behavior, they’re modifying it, reprogramming her personality to become someone else.
A killer.


It was published not too long before you said you read the book in question.
The title begins with an 'M' like you remembered.
The main character is a girl who undergoes experimental brain surgery after an accident and gains an enhanced intellect.
I checked the Google Books preview and found a scene where she performs brain surgery on herself while in the shower and another where she sees a raccoon.



Yep this is exactly it, thanks
